# Linguistic Term for the Opposite/Converse of an Apocopic Form?

Tags: terminology

When you have an apocopic form (e.g. *radio* (the device) is an apocopic form of *radiorreceptor* in Spanish), is there a converse term that can be used to say, using the example above, that *radiorreceptor* is an *x* form of *radio* in Spanish?

I suppose I am looking for a sort of linguistic term for the antonym of apocope/apocopic.  Is it just “full form”?

Thanks!

Comment: I’d probably just call it the _unapocopated form_.

Comment: That's overnegated. Why not just the _pocopated form_?

Comment: @jlawler, I don’t think the prefix is Greek *[ἀ-](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/ἀ-#Ancient_Greek)*—rather, it is Greek *[ἀπο-](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/ἀπο-#Ancient_Greek)*, cognate with Latin *ab*, English “off”, etc), meaning “from/away from” (cf. “*ab*lative”).  So *unapocopic/unapocopated* is probably fine, if such a term is even worthy of definition.

Answer (score 1):

Apocope refers to any deletion of material at the end. Something where there is no deletion at the end is not a coherent linguistic concept, so there is no such general term. However, in the context of surface word relations, where there are two words and one can be seen as the product of truncating a final part (e.g. a stem or syllable) to derive another worm, we usually call the fuller form "the base (form)". However, "base" is not limited to apocope, it is *any* original form from which a derived word is created. There is no term for "base for apocopation of a stem" or anything like that.

Comment: So, you are saying that the entries at [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/radio#Spanish), Spanish-language [Wiktionary](https://es.wiktionary.org/wiki/radio), and Spanish-language [Wikipedia](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apócope) that all define *radio* as an apocopic form of *radiorreceptor*, are using the term incorrectly?  Furthermore, that only (to use Spanish again for an example) a word like *bueno*, truncated to *buen* before certain words would be an example of apocope?

Comment: You shouldn't tell me what I am saying, especially when you are wrong in restating what I said. Bueno → buen could be an example of apocope, if you assume that specific derivation.

Comment: I’m not—it was a question, meant to obtain clarification—thus, the *question mark*.  Could you clarify how I have misunderstood what you are saying?

Comment: I said nothing at all about Wiktionary or Wikipedia, I said something about what the linguistic term apocope means.

Comment: Could you answer my question about those three sources if I were to emend the first four words of my comment above from “So, you are saying…?” to  “So, would you say…?”